# nimbus as defalut

Tags: java, netbeans-7, nimbus

I'm using java 7 update 17  and netBeans IDE 7.3  I would to set the nimbus as default for every GUI project  but  oracle website instruction not working .

> how to set nimbus  at default for every project ?

I write my code manually without use palette , or drag and drop .

and this instruction does not work http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html

Comment: How are creating your UIs?

Comment: manually , but I m using netbeans IDE without drag and drop property

Comment: If you create a `JFrame`, Netbeans will install Nimbus by default

Comment: It's not working , if I uses this code ........
o the event-dispatching thread before creating the graphical user interface (GUI):
import javax.swing.UIManager.*;

try {
    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
}

Comment: the graphic will changing to nimbus , I would to use this for every project without write that code repeatedly

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  Try putting `System.out.println` in the loop and output the `info.getName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following called at the start of the main

```
try {
    for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        System.out.println("LAF: " + info.getName());
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            //break;
        }
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
    | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

gave

```
LAF: Metal
LAF: Nimbus
LAF: CDE/Motif
LAF: Windows
LAF: Windows Classic
```

It's copied from the code of the main of a generated JFrame form in NetBeans.

After that

```
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

And I guess there it must be going awry.

Maybe you have some command line options, system java settings, selecting a LAF already and "extending" Nimbus (Plastic or so)?